# Error when trying to run on release mode Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, linker-errors

I developed a project and while working on it I run it on debug mode, it works perfectly.  When I try to run it on release mode I get the following error:

> "error LNK1201: error writing to program database 'projectname.pdb'
>   check for insufficient disk space, invalid path, or insufficient
>   privilege "

The disk space shouldn't be a problem and I checked the running configurations and they seem to be ok.

Comment: Try a clean and rebuild?  Reboot and try compiling again in case there is something in the background that has the file locked?

Comment: I tried that, it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your program database file 'projectname.pdb' for release mode is corrupted. If you delete the file and rebuild the project a new one will be generated. You can find the file in 'projectname/x64/Release'